# How to I direct the output of a VM in GCP to stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm wondering how I direct the output from my VM to stackdriver?  and how do I set the properties of log entries?  E.g. error/warning/info, and name info.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a Stackdriver Logging agent that you can install onto your GCP and AWS VMs. You can configure the agent to grab your logs and send them to Stackdriver.

Here's the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/. It goes over installation of the agent, configuring syslog, structuring your payloads (including setting log severity), etc...